# Symbolizing ArcGIS services in Leaflet

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, map-service

I am trying to add layers from this ArcGIS MapServer to my Leaflet webmap:
http://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/igems_haz/MapServer

This code added the weather warnings layer (12), but used the default blue symbol for all of the feature types.

```
var URL2 = 'http://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/igems_haz/MapServer/12/'

var warnings = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: URL2,
    useCors: false
    });

warnings.addTo(weather);
weather.addTo(map);
```

Looking at this service description page, it seems that there is are preset symbols configured on the server: 
http://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/igems_haz/MapServer/12

From example for an Ash Warning:

```
Symbol:
Style: esriSFSSolid 
Color: [169, 169, 169, 255] 
Outline:
  Style: esriSLSSolid 
  Color: [0, 0, 0, 0] 
Width: 0
```

Is there an option for L.esri.featureLayer to use the preset symobology?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Esri Leaflet Renderers](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-renderers):

> Plugin for Esri Leaflet to use drawing information defined in the
>   feature service

Comment: That worked. Was very easy to implement too.  Thank you very much!!!